With Bazel is it possible to make configuration values in (e.g. in .bazelrc) dynamic?
In a Bazel configured project I want to move away from a wrapper script which runs Bazel and provides extra arguments, e.g.
bazel-build-wrapper.sh:
EXECUTION_LOG_FILE_NAME=$(create_unique_filename_from_args $@)
bazel build --execution_log_json_file="${EXECUTION_LOG_FILE_NAME}" $@

(this is quite simplified just to show the intention)
Another use case would be to provide --action_env values, e.g. in order to pass system specific values for PATH and other values we need from the outside for projects which are not fully hermetic yet, but cannot be statically hard-coded.
A workaround for the latter case would be to provide configuration files before running Bazel and have import <dynamic-config-file> statements in order to affect all bazel invocations without a wrapper.
While this approach seems a bit complicated to me and requires steps to be executed in advance, it works for system specific configuration but it can't be specific for each run (e.g. for multiple bazel invocations in a row or for different arguments).
So, are there ways to "calculate" certain values (e.g. by running a script or macro) in .bazelrc or are there different approaches to the provided use cases?
